# Drupal css not updating after change

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8

I'm new to Drupal and PHP. I have a project where I have updated the css and saved in in my custom theme.

My problem is that it is not updating when I refresh the page.

Is there something I have to do to make that take???

I know I have the right file and the right selector...

Thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are working in a development or staging enviornment:

1. Go to Configuration -> Performance. Set page cache to no-caching.
2. Click 'Clear Caching', or via command line use drush cr.  This will add a new 'cache-buster' query string to your css, such as main.css?dfweaf where dfweaf changes after a cache rebuild.
3. Look into setting up a settings.local.php and development.services.yml to disable various layers of caching while working.
4. While working in your browser, open developer tools and on the Network tab check 'Disable cache'.  When refreshing the page, right click on the refresh icon and choose 'Empty Cache and Hard Reload' to flush your browser cache files. This works in Chrome.
5. If changing Javascript files, update the VERSION number in your libraries.yml file

Answer (score 5):

You need to go to:

```
Drupal > Performance > Clear cache
```

Or if you have installed `drush`, then you can run below command to clear the cache:

```
drush cc
```

**Note:** Adding my comment as answer, so that OP can mark the question as done/answered.

Comment: You can also do `drush cr`